# Django query is it possible to use self

Tags: django, django-models

I am wondering if is possible to use self parameters in django models

lets says in  `MyModel` I have `date_from` and `date_to`

I wish to select the models where `date_from != date_to`

how is it possible to achieve it?

I need something like

```
myvar = MyModel.objects.all().exclude(self.date_from=self.date_to)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, given `date_from` and `date_to` are fiels, you can use an [**`F`**-expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to reference to another column:

```
from django.db.models import F

myvar = MyModel.objects.exclude(date_from=F('date_to'))
```

The `F`-expression here thus contains a string, and acts as a "representative" of the field. Here we thus will obtain all `MyModel`s where the two columns `date_from` and `date_to` are *different*.

This will thus result in a query that looks more or less like:

```
SELECT mymodel.*
FROM mymodel
WHERE NOT(date_from = date_to)
```

(Django normally mentions all the fields it selects *explicitly*, this is more to show that the filtering will be done at the database level)

Comment: Thank you man for the amazing answer  everything works like a charm! :)